# Error looping through resuts of join statement using entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using entity frame work and i'm attempting a join.  The join executes just fine, but i'm getting an error when I try to loop through my results.  See below

```
 var items = from a in db.ActivityLogs
                            from v in db.Vehicles
                            where (a.PlateID1 == v.PlateID || a.PlateID2 == v.PlateID) && v.Alerted == true
                            select new { a, v };
```

this executes fine, then I get the error

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[DB.ActivityLog,DB.Vehicle]' to type 'DB.ActivityLog'.

on the following code

```
foreach (ActivityLog l in items)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `new { a, v }` is not an `ActivityLog`.

Answer (score 3):

You have projected to anonymous type hence, it cannot be casted to Activity log.

```
var items = (from a in db.ActivityLogs
                        from v in db.Vehicles
                        where (a.PlateID1 == v.PlateID || a.PlateID2 == 
                        v.PlateID) && v.Alerted == true
                        select new { a, v }).ToArray();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.writeLine(item.a);
    Console.writeLine(item.v);

}
```

or

```
 var items = (from a in db.ActivityLogs
                        from v in db.Vehicles
                        where (a.PlateID1 == v.PlateID || a.PlateID2 == 
                        v.PlateID) && v.Alerted == true
                        select new ActivityLog
                        { 
                           A= a, // Pseudo code
                           V = v, // Pseudo code map to essential properties
                        }).ToArray();

foreach (ActivityLog l in items)
```

Comment: Your class should have properties to accomadate A & V.  Its not correct synatax . its a pseudo code. If your activity log is DTO type class you could use properties that are needed for it.